# fgetpos available in Go? Want to find File.Position

Tags: go

I have a `File` and I want to find the file offset/position, what would be `fgetpos` in `stdio`. I can't seem to find it in http://golang.org/pkg/io/. Do I have to count it myself or is there a build in method?

Comment: The 'io' package contains code for general i/o not specific to files. Files are operating system related and so are in the 'os' package.

Comment: Yes but I wanted to do it through an interface (as it happens I was writing my own 'class' to provide a mock File for testing in addition to this).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should be able to do a `Seek()` to 0 bytes from the current position, which returns the resulting position. I'm not 100% sure the result is the absolute position you're after, but I would expect it to be.

```
offset, err := f.Seek(0, io.SeekCurrent)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
// offset is the current position
```

Comment: Genious. I completely missed the return value and was just about to give up when you saved my ass. Tested and works, thanks!

Comment: Note, this **won't** work for files opened with `O_APPEND` flag. There is a warning in the `Seek` documentation about the undefined behavior, and more detail is available here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12710. There is a race condition, but if locking is ensured (`syscall.Flock` so other processes are blocked plus some `sync.Mutex` so other goroutines in current process are also blocked) then `Stat` method can provide current "position" with `FileInfo.Size`.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```golang
currentPosition, err := file.Seek(0, 1)
```

i read it from here:

https://cihanozhan.medium.com/file-operations-in-golang-292825c9fb3d

Answer (score -1):

If it translates to syscall lseek(), it is quite expensive and can end up with expensive performance penalty compared to C ftell(), for example.